# magento - slow add to cart - high number of queries

Tags: performance, magento, cart

we are running an Enterprise instance and see some strange behaviour on add to cart where a transaction trace shows inventory & status being checked multiple times - even for a small'ish basket (e.g. 20 items).  We run new-relic and can see hundreds of calls in the trace and while they respond quickly they add up given they are called so many times.  Attached shows a sample trace for a simple cart add.  We are running nginx, varnish, apc as core config.  Any ideas/help greatly appreciated.  Anyone seen similar before?

load time: 14,871

98.82% Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::dispatch

6.13%

156 fast method calls        2.050s 1.0 0.01%
catalogrule_product_price - SELECT   2.050s 1.0
catalog_product_entity_group_price - SELECT 2.054  s 0.0
catalog_product_flat_1 - SELECT      2.059  s
cataloginventory_stock_status - SELECT       2.061  s
catalog_product_flat_1 - SELECT      2.073  s
cataloginventory_stock_status - SELECT       2.082  s
catalog_product_flat_1 - SELECT      2.087  s
cataloginventory_stock_status - SELECT       2.097  s
cataloginventory_stock_status - SELECT       2.104  s
and so on for hundreds of calls..

Comment: this is a direct consequence of the Magento EAV database structure. there will be a lot of calls, especially if configurable products are added to the cart.
You can negate this with some clever caching strategies

Answer (score 0):

try clever caching in magento. For example you can use memcache to minimise Database calls.